# Random failure to insert record into access database

Tags: vb.net

I have been getting random failures to write records into the access database that does our time keeping. It works 99% of the time and I can't find any pattern to why it fails. Is there a better way to do this? If it's a network issue, can I make it continue to try to write with a DO while loop until a sql statement finds the line that was just written?

I implemented an error log file, but when it fails to write, it doesn't show anything in the error log

```
    Try


        Select Case ComboBox2.Text
            Case "002"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[002]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "006"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[006]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "007"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[007]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "008"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[008]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "009"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[009]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "011"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[011]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "012"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[012]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "015"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[015]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "017"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[017]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "020"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[020]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "022"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[022]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

            Case "027"
                sqlQry1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],[027]) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"

        End Select


        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D", Job_Date)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ComboBox1.Text)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EWC", ComboBox3.Text)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q", TextBox3.Text)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_num", TextBox4.Text)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@print_num", TextBox5.Text)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prim", L_Hours)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WCC", TextBox6.Text)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_in", Auto_In)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_out", Job_Time)
        sqlQry1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OP_Code", L_Hours)
        sqlQry1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error code L07 -- Failed To Insert New Record During Job In")
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(Error_Path)
            sw.WriteLine(" ")
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "   Error code L07 " + ComboBox1.Text + "  " + Environment.MachineName + "  " + ex.Message)
            If TextBox7.Text > "" Then
                sw.WriteLine("Inputs: Qty " + TextBox3.Text + "  Job # " + TextBox4.Text + "  Print # " + TextBox5.Text + "  WC " + TextBox6.Text + "  Code " + ComboBox3.Text + " Time In " + TextBox7.Text + "Time Out " + Job_Time)
                sw.WriteLine("SQL Statement =  " + sqlQry1.CommandText)
            Else
                sw.WriteLine("Inputs: Qty " + TextBox3.Text + "  Job # " + TextBox4.Text + "  Print # " + TextBox5.Text + "  WC " + TextBox6.Text + "  Code " + ComboBox3.Text)
                sw.WriteLine("SQL Statement =  " + sqlQry1.CommandText)
                sw.WriteLine(" ")
            End If
        End Using
    End Try

    con1.Dispose()
```

It doesn't give me any errors, when the data is checked, the record isn't there.

Comment: Given that there is only one column difference between all of your Sql statements, I think this would be an acceptable case for string concatenation when it comes to the COLUMNS part of the statement. This would also help to reduce the potential problem areas

Comment: `con1.Close()` and `con1.Dispose()` do the same thing, so you don't need to call it twice.  There should be a strong preference to put those disposable objects into Using - End Using blocks to take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your intermitant problems might be with `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

I have used the `.Add` method for parameters. I had to guess at the datatypes. You will have to check your database for the actual OleDbTypes. Then be sure that your .net type of the parameter values match. They should be validated before you assign them to the `.Value`. You may just need a CInt or CDate if you are sure the conversion will succeed.

I also used interpolated strings, the ones that start with a $. They are easier to read. The variables are just placed in line surrounded by braces { }.

```vb
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim sqlQuery = $"INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out], [{ComboBox2.Text}] ) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code);"
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection String")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@D", OleDbType.Date).Value = Job_Date
                .Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
                .Add("@EWC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox3.Text
                .Add("@Q", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
                .Add("@job_num", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
                .Add("@print_num", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
                .Add("@Prim", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = L_Hours
                .Add("@WCC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text
                .Add("@t_in", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Auto_In
                .Add("@t_out", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Job_Time
                .Add("@OP_Code", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = L_Hours
            End With
            Try
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error code L07 -- Failed To Insert New Record During Job In")
                Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(Error_Path)
                    sw.WriteLine(" ")
                    sw.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}  Error code L07 {ComboBox1.Text} { Environment.MachineName} {ex.Message}")
                    Dim nextLine = $"Inputs: Qty {TextBox3.Text}  Job # {TextBox4.Text }  Print # {TextBox5.Text}  WC {TextBox6.Text}  Code {ComboBox3.Text}"
                    If TextBox7.Text <> "" Then
                        nextLine &= $" Time In {TextBox7.Text} Time Out {Job_Time}"
                    End If
                    sw.WriteLine(nextLine)
                    sw.WriteLine($"SQL Statement =  {cmd.CommandText}")
                    sw.WriteLine(" ")
                End Using
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

This is the code you asked about in the comment.

```
Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
If rowsAffected < 1 Then 
    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End If
```

No, you would not want to run .ExecuteNonQuery again. You would want to inform the user that the Insert didn't succeed.

In regards to the SQL statement... The $ preceding the string indicates that it is an interpolated string which is available in Visual Basic 14 and later versions.. The value in the braces (curly brackets) will be inserted into the string. This should match exactly the the Insert statements you presented in your Select Case. From your code it appears that ComboBox2.Text contains a column name. If this is not true, please explain your code further.

**EDIT 2**

```
    Dim sqlQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out], [{0}] ) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code);", ComboBox2.Text)
```

Comment: I have formatted the sql statement to add the parameters as you have shown with the exception of the comboBox2.text, it wouldn't work for me the way you had it shown. I added that in as shown below. Do you think it would be a good idea to add this code? '  Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()                         If rowsAffected < 1 Then
                            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End If '

Comment: I am not a professional programmer (obviously), I am a tool & die maker. I am still using VB 8 (2005). That's why the formatting didn't work as you described.

Comment: @bgm1956 For individual programmers Visual Studio 2019 Community is free for the download. It is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

There's many possibilities here, so in order to narrow it down, you should declare your variables in a way that reduces the chances of problems. For example, from your code snippet, I can't tell where or how you are declaring your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects. I see you've run across the Using statement in your exception handler. You should also use `Using` for any `IDisposable` object. Also, you can greatly simply that block of `Select Case` code. Take the following into consideration:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

' This would naturally be located in a centralized place in your code base,
' and is only in this Form class for example purposes:
Private Const CONN_STRING As String = "your connection string"

Private Sub Foo()

    Dim myQuery As String = "INSERT INTO [Job Times] ([Date],[Employee], [EmpWC],[Qnty],[Job #],[Print #],[Primary], [WC],[Time In], [Time Out],{0}) VALUES (@D, @Name,@EWC,@Q,@job_num,@print_num,@Prim,@WCC ,@t_in,@t_out,@OP_Code)"
    myQuery = String.Format(myQuery, ComboBox2.Text)

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(CONN_STRING)

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(myQuery)

            With cmd

                Try

                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text

                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@D", Job_Date)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ComboBox2.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@EWC", ComboBox3.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q", TextBox3.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_num", TextBox4.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@print_num", TextBox5.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prim", L_Hours)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@WCC", TextBox6.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_in", Auto_In)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_out", Job_Time)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OP_Code", L_Hours)

                    .ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As Exception

                    MessageBox.Show("Error code L07 -- Failed To Insert New Record During Job In")

                    Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(Error_Path)
                        sw.WriteLine(" ")
                        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "   Error code L07 " + ComboBox2.Text + "  " + Environment.MachineName + "  " + ex.Message)
                        If TextBox7.Text > "" Then
                            sw.WriteLine("Inputs: Qty " + TextBox3.Text + "  Job # " + TextBox4.Text + "  Print # " + TextBox5.Text + "  WC " + TextBox6.Text + "  Code " + ComboBox3.Text + " Time In " + TextBox7.Text + "Time Out " + Job_Time)
                            sw.WriteLine("SQL Statement =  " + .CommandText)
                        Else
                            sw.WriteLine("Inputs: Qty " + TextBox3.Text + "  Job # " + TextBox4.Text + "  Print # " + TextBox5.Text + "  WC " + TextBox6.Text + "  Code " + ComboBox3.Text)
                            sw.WriteLine("SQL Statement =  " + .CommandText)
                            sw.WriteLine(" ")
                        End If
                    End Using

                End Try

            End With

        End Using

    End Using

End Sub

End Class
```

1. Note the String.Format function, which replaces "{0}" with the one field name in your query that is different based on the value of `ComboBox2`.
2. Note the `Using` statements for declaring the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`
3. Note that the connection and command objects are only in scope for the time they are used.

There are many possibilities of why some rows aren't getting written, but based on only your code snippet, it's a guess. Perhaps the SqlCommand isn't getting properly disposed and it's being reused? I suggest cleaning up your code as I have here, first, then see what the outcome is.

**DISCLAIMER: This is untested code.**